# swift function return object need argument

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an `SMUser` Class which has `getUserFromKeychain` method, in its declaration there are no arguments but when I call the method Xcode tells me to put `SMUser` as an argument ??? Am I missing something? Here is my method declaration which is in `SMUser` class :

```
func getUserFromKeychain() -> (SMUser) {
    var userDatas: NSDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user") as! NSDictionary
    var user: SMUser = SMUser.init(userSettings: userDatas)
    return user
}
```

The method call in `SMLoginController` :

```
var user: SMUser = SMUser.getUserFromKeychain()
```

Comment: "when I call the method Xcode tell me to put SMUser argument" Do not say what Xcode "tell me to put". Copy and paste into your question _the actual error message_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot say `SMUser.getUserFromKeychain()` - because you have declared `getUserFromKeyChain` like this:

```
func getUserFromKeychain() -> (SMUser) {
```

That means `getUserFromKeyChain` is an *instance* method, not a *class* method. You have to send it to an *instance*:

```
let SMUser : user = SMUser()
user.getUserForKeychain()
```

Or, instead, when you declare it, declare it *as a class method*:

```
class func getUserFromKeychain() -> (SMUser) {
```

One or the other. I suspect that the second one is what you want.

Comment: Yes It's an error when I wrote my question. I well have a declaration without argument but when I call my method xcode tell me to put an argument

Comment: If you don't show your real code you cannot expect to get a real answer. Do not lie to Stack Overflow. :) Don't type your code; copy and paste it. Show _real_ code.

Comment: Yes sorry the xcode error is : SMLoginController.swift:41:54: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Comment: In Objective-c I would declare my getUserFromKeychain method as : 

+(SMUser *)getUserFromKeychain {

}

Comment: And the Swift equivalent, as I just told you in my answer, is `class func`. So just say that in your declaration.

Comment: Yes thanks it works :) I did not know how to declare my method as class method in Swift